# 外部のサーバーのphpのバージョンなどを調べるには？

Tags: php, apache

自分の管理していない外部のサーバーの`php`バージョンや`apache`のバージョンを調べる方法はあるんでしょうか？

以下の様な情報を知ることはできますか？

- php などのランタイムの情報
- apache などのウェブサーバーの情報
- メモリやCPUなどのハードウェアスペック

これは一般的に管理者しか知り得ない情報なのかと思いますが、
どの程度の情報まで外部からアクセスできるんでしょうか？
大規模な運営をしているヤフージャパンのサーバースペックやソフトウェアのバージョンなどを
知りたいと思っています

Comment: サーバーの応答を見るとか[Netcraftで調べるとか](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.yahoo.co.jp "Site report for www.yahoo.co.jp")ぐらいしかできないんじゃないですかね。

Answer (score 1):

基本的には「知ることはできない」との認識で差支ありません。

サーバーやアプリケーションの構成は「大は小を兼ねる」ことはあまりないので、Yahooさん規模のトラフィックがあるサービスを運営しようと検討中でなければ、これらの情報を直接知っても(参考にはなっても)そのまま適用できることはあまり多くないように感じます。